# Finding number of way to combine words with at least $1$ vowel

Tags: combinatorics

> a) In an alphabet consisting of $18$ letters, how many "words" with word length $4$ is it possible to make when no consecutive letters can be equal?

I found this value to $88434$ (confirmed to be correct)

> b) Assume the alphabet in a) consists of $10$ consonants and $8$ vowels. How many of the words from a) contain at least one vowel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count how many words has all consonants and subtract it from the whole possible words in a). 
Thus we have $10 \cdot 9 \cdot 9 \cdot 9=7290$ words with all consonants. 
Now the number of words with a least one vowel are $88434-7290=81144$